# Passing list data from View to Controller in MVC core

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to pass a list of items from a view to the controller with a selected option on the list.

My View has the following loop for each record:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Model[i].Name
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Model[i].DateofBirth
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input asp-for="@Model[i].Selected">
                </td>
            </tr>
            
        }
```

The controllers post parameter accepts a list of the model

It all works perfectly until the list is over 101 records long then nothing is being passed to the controller on submit. Any Ideas Why?

Comment: Hi@Stephen Waldock, I try to upload more than 101 records long and controller can receive normally, Are you uploading only the data shown in your question?  Do you receive any error like `InvalidDataException: Form value count limit 1024 exceeded` or just receive null in your controller?

Comment: Just null in my controller there are more fields than the ones shown

Comment: I think you need to show details.